# Where can I find the exact grey color of the unread message // mail // Gmail

Tags: android, colors, grayscale

In my app, I will have a ListView with read and unread items, so I would like to use the same colors than the latest AOSP.

The 2 grey color shades of the messaging app sounds quite correct and I would like to know where I can have a look in Android source code to find the exact same grey. (read = white?)

Note: using a screenshot and a color picker is not acceptable, I don't want to "guess" the correct hexadecimal code.

[image]

I am totally aware that I could use my own colors, but using the system one sounds better.

The Android design website doesn't give me any clue at the color section: http://developer.android.com/design/style/color.html

Any idea/suggestion?

Comment: "I would like to use the same colors than, the platform" -- that is not the platform. That is the Messaging app. If you want to know what color some version of some app uses, go look at the source code. Bear in mind that an app can change its colors in different versions, and that device manufacturers can change colors on their own modified version of AOSP apps.

Comment: "I would like to use the same colors than, the latest AOSP", I will fix that in the question. I just want to "feel like" I have the correct latest color

Comment: Again, the AOSP does not have these colors -- particular apps in the AOSP do. Messaging may use different colors than Mail, and neither of those necessarily use the same colors as the proprietary Gmail app. And none of those colors are necessarily defined in the SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lighter color is: #FFFFFF

The darker color is: #EEEEEE

Comment: Where can I find that in source? Did you simply use a color picker from your computer or is that in source code?

Comment: It's not in the source, but it's accurate (Photoshop).

Comment: If I do not find an answer in the source in the next hours/days, I will trust you and accept, but I have a requirement to get 100% the same hexa than AOSP

Comment: And, if I had to guess, this is the source file where those values are hard-coded for this specific app: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/blob/master/res/values/colors.xml

Comment: @CommonsWare Perfect answer! If you post a link, I will accept, otherwise, I will accept cynicalMe answer

Comment: @Waza_Be: Actually, it's not a "perfect answer". These are the colors used by the Messaging app. They are not necessarily the colors used by Mail, or the non-AOSP Gmail, or anything else.

Comment: The perfect answer was the color used in AOSP messaging app ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I use th[e Eye Dropper Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eye-dropper/hmdcmlfkchdmnmnmheododdhjedfccka?hl=en) to figure out color codes from any web page

Comment: Unless you are using a tool which loads an uncompressed raw bitmap and displays it as the same, there is no way to know with an eye dropper that the colour is the same. With a screenshot, You would also need to understand how the display driver renders the image. If the pixel selected is in the middle of a large area of uniform colour, you could reasonably expect is it the same but as programmers, we should strive for accuracy.  In this case, the only way to know for sure is to examine the source code.